# disable dropdown list if not contain any value using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

How do I make a dropdown list disable if it doesn't contain any value using `foreach` to get data in database?

This is my current code:

```
<?php
  $aFilters['AgentName'];

  echo "<select name='AgentName' id='selAgentName'>";
  echo "<option value=''>Select Agent</option>";

  foreach($agentsName as $ar) {
    echo "<option value='$ar->id'>$ar->first_name$ar->last_name</option>";
  }

  echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
<?php
  $aFilters['AgentName'];


    $i = 0;

  foreach($agentsName as $ar) {
    echo "<option value='$ar->id'>$ar->first_name$ar->last_name</option>";
    $i++;
  }
  ?>
<select <?php if ($i > 0) { echo " disabled "} ?> name='AgentName' id='selAgentName'>
<option value=''>Select Agent</option>
</select>
```

remove drop down script:

```
<?php 
$aFilters['AgentName'];
$i = 0;

foreach($agentsName as $ar) { 
    $i++; 
    if ($i>1) { 
        echo "<select name='AgentName' id='selAgentName'>";
        echo "<option value='$ar->id'>$ar->first_name$ar->last_name</option>"; 
    } 
} 
?>
<option value=''>Select Agent</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT: Fixed all bugs**

Comment: if  I need to remove dropdown list it not contain any value how this?

Comment: Updated again, sorry I had a mistake

Comment: @mohammad Updated again

Comment: @mohammad updated again :) sorry I just noticed another problem

Comment: <?php
                        $aFilters['AgentName'];

                        $i = 0;

                        foreach($agentsName as $ar) {
                            $i++;
                            if ($i>1) {
                                echo "<select name='AgentName' id='selAgentName'>";
                                echo "<option value='$ar->id'>$ar->first_name$ar->last_name</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>                     
make this change to work perfect very thanks Mor Haviv

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator with `count()` :

```
 echo "<select " . (count($agentsName) > 0 ? "" : "disabled") . " name='AgentName' id='selAgentName'>";
```

If you want to remove dropdown list in case there are no options provided by array (empty array) :

```
if(count($agentsName) > 0) {
   echo "<select name='AgentName' id='selAgentName'>";
   echo "<option value=''>Select Agent</option>";

   foreach($agentsName as $ar) {
      echo "<option value='$ar->id'>$ar->first_name$ar->last_name</option>";
   }
}
```

Comment: if I need to remove dropdown list it not contain any value how this?

Comment: again very Thanks but I make  mark as answered to Mor Haviv becuase make update before you insert solution i am so sorry very very thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name='abc'>
<?php if(count($data)>0){ ?>
   @foreach ($data as $i)
      <option value="$i['id']">$i['Data']</option>
   @endforeach
<?php } else { ?>
      <option value="0">No Result</option>
<?php } ?>
```

See, if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
 $aFilters['AgentName'];

 if(count($agentsName)>0)
 {
  echo "<select name='AgentName' id='selAgentName'>";
  echo "<option value=''>Select Agent</option>";

  foreach($agentsName as $ar) {
  echo "<option value='$ar->id'>$ar->first_name$ar->last_name</option>";
 }
   echo "</select>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: if I need to remove dropdown list it not contain any value how this?

Comment: then just add else part for that if and disabled dropdown list

Comment: Thanks Kavita but must change sizeof to count its work very Thanks